# Icon appears when selecting an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I'm working on the palette project and trying to appear icon when selecting an image.

Icon is now placed next to beige, but I'm struggling to make it disappear when not selecting an image.

Below images describe how I imagine for this project.

Please help.

[image]

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  color: #FFF;
}

.board {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.board-nav-indicator {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
  /*background-color:red;*/
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left top, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  transition:all 0.3s;
  transform:translateX(0);
  z-index:1;
}
[data-page='0'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform:translateX(0);
}
[data-page='1'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform:translateX(100%);
}
[data-page='2'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform:translateX(200%);
}

.board-nav-buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}

.board-pages {
  position:absolute;
  top:75px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 75px);
  overflow:hidden;
}
.board-page {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transition:all 0.4s;
  transform:translateX(0);
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: #262931;
}

.grid-row-theme .grid-item-theme {
  max-width: 130px;
}

#align-left {
  float: left;
  color: #747474;
}

#align-right {
  float: right;
  color: #9CC8E3;
}

.grid-item {
  flex:0 1 25%;
  padding:6px;
}

.grid-item-theme {
  flex:0 1 25%;
  padding:6px;
}

.grid-row {
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.grid-row .grid-item {
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:110px;
}

.grid-item-content {
  text-align:left;
  font-family: "mr-eaves-modern";
  font-size:0.3rem;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}


.pick-palette img{
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
}

#dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% 0 6% 0;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.grid-item-content {
   height: 26px;
   line-height: 26px;
   position: relative;
}
.grid-item-content i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

 .grid-item-content {
   height: 26px;
   line-height: 26px;
   position: relative;
}
.grid-item-content i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Omnibag Project</title>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body> 

<div class="board-pages">

      <div class="board-page">

        <div class="grid-item-theme" id="dropdown-menu">Warm<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i></div>

        <div class="trending-above-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">Trending</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>   

        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item grid-beige">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />   
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Beige
              <i class="material-icons more-icon">more_horiz</i>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-camel">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Camel
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-salmon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Salmon Pink
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-navajo">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Navajo White
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-niagara">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Niagara
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-primrose">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Primrose
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-lapis">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Lapis Blue
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
        

        <div class="after-first-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">Newly added</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div> 


        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item grid-pale">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Pale Blue
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-moss">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Moss Green
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-melon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Melon
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-chiffon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Chiffon
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-island">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Island
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-dogwood">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Dogwood
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-greenery">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Greenery
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        

        <div class="after-first-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">All Warm Colors</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>    
        <div class="grid-row">

          <div class="grid-item grid-ivory">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Ivory
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-honeydew">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Honeydew
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-lavender">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Lavender
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-canary">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Canary
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-hazelnut">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Hazelnut
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-kale">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Kale
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-sharkskin">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content sharkskin">
              Sharkskin
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.typekit.net/hoc0zbs.js"></script>
  <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>

  <script>

    $(".board-pages .grid-item").on("click",function(){
      $(this).parents('.board-page').find('.pick-palette').removeClass("pick-palette");
    $(this).addClass( "pick-palette" );
    });

    $(".board-pages .grid-item-pattern-board").on("click",function(){
      $(this).parents('.board-page').find('.pick-palette').removeClass("pick-palette");
    $(this).addClass( "pick-palette" );
    });
 

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1st you can add same event to different selector like this:
`$(".board-pages .grid-item-pattern-board, .board-pages .grid-item")` seperate by `,`

2nd I check if the clicked one already has class means it is active already, then I deactive all. If not active yet, deactive all then active this one.

```
  $(".board-pages .grid-item-pattern-board, .board-pages .grid-item").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("pick-palette")) {
      $(this).parents('.board-page').find('.pick-palette').removeClass("pick-palette");
    } else {
      $(this).parents('.board-page').find('.pick-palette').removeClass("pick-palette");
      $(this).addClass("pick-palette");
    }
  });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #FFF;
}

.board {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.board-nav-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  /*background-color:red;*/
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left top, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  transform: translateX(0);
  z-index: 1;
}

[data-page='0'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

[data-page='1'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

[data-page='2'] .board-nav-indicator {
  transform: translateX(200%);
}

.board-nav-buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.board-pages {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 75px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.board-page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  transform: translateX(0);
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #262931;
}

.grid-row-theme .grid-item-theme {
  max-width: 130px;
}

#align-left {
  float: left;
  color: #747474;
}

#align-right {
  float: right;
  color: #9CC8E3;
}

.grid-item {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
  padding: 6px;
}

.grid-item-theme {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
  padding: 6px;
}

.grid-row {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.grid-row .grid-item {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 110px;
}

.grid-item-content {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "mr-eaves-modern";
  font-size: 0.3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.pick-palette img {
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
}

#dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% 0 6% 0;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.grid-item-content {
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  position: relative;
}

.grid-item-content i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.grid-item-content {
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  position: relative;
}

.grid-item-content i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Omnibag Project</title>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="board-pages">

    <div class="board-page">

      <div class="grid-item-theme" id="dropdown-menu">Warm<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i></div>

      <div class="trending-above-palette">
        <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">Trending</div>
        <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid-row">
        <div class="grid-item grid-beige">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Beige
            <i class="material-icons more-icon">more_horiz</i>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-camel">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Camel
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-salmon">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Salmon Pink
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-navajo">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Navajo White
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-niagara">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Niagara
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-primrose">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Primrose
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-lapis">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Lapis Blue
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>


      <div class="after-first-palette">
        <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">Newly added</div>
        <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      </div>


      <div class="grid-row">
        <div class="grid-item grid-pale">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Pale Blue
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-moss">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Moss Green
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-melon">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Melon
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-chiffon">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Chiffon
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-island">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Island
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-dogwood">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Dogwood
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-greenery">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Greenery
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="after-first-palette">
        <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">All Warm Colors</div>
        <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-row">

        <div class="grid-item grid-ivory">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Ivory
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-honeydew">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Honeydew
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-lavender">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Lavender
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-canary">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Canary
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-hazelnut">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Hazelnut
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-kale">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content">
            Kale
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-sharkskin">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />
          <div class="grid-item-content sharkskin">
            Sharkskin
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/hoc0zbs.js"></script>
    <script>
      try {
        Typekit.load({
          async: true
        });
      } catch (e) {}
    </script>

    <script>
      $(".board-pages .grid-item-pattern-board, .board-pages .grid-item").on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("pick-palette")) {
          $(this).parents('.board-page').find('.pick-palette').removeClass("pick-palette");
        } else {
          $(this).parents('.board-page').find('.pick-palette').removeClass("pick-palette");
          $(this).addClass("pick-palette");
        }
      });
    </script>
```